# Abysmal postgres query performance when joining by jsonb_exists (question mark operator)

Tags: postgresql

Our application recently changed how some data was modeled, changing the schema to add a jsonb array column, and populating it from data in another column.

We're finding that the new queries joining on this column are unacceptably slow against our full data set, and are in a tight spot as we're forced to still use the old queries until this is resolved.

The main table we're querying on is defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE public.visit (
  visit_key CHARACTER VARYING PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  store_key CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  launch_key CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  when_ TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  page CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  ip CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  useragent CHARACTER VARYING,
  referrer CHARACTER VARYING,
  visitor CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  country CHARACTER VARYING,
  region CHARACTER VARYING,
  city CHARACTER VARYING,
  vars JSONB,
  stops JSONB,
  FOREIGN KEY (launch_key) REFERENCES public.launch (launch_key)
  MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (store_key) REFERENCES public.store (store_key)
  MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
CREATE INDEX visit_store_key_idx ON visit USING BTREE (store_key);
CREATE INDEX visit_launch_key_idx ON visit USING BTREE (launch_key);
CREATE INDEX visit_visitor_idx ON visit USING BTREE (visitor);
CREATE INDEX visit_stops_idx ON visit USING GIN (stops);
CREATE INDEX visit_when__idx ON visit USING BTREE (when_);
```

Our old "fast" query and corresponding plan looks like this:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE)
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', "public"."visit"."when_" :: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'),
    count("public"."visit"."visitor"),
    count(DISTINCT "public"."visit"."visitor")
FROM "public"."visit" join "public"."launch" ON ("public"."visit"."launch_key" = "public"."launch"."launch_key")
WHERE (
    "public"."visit"."store_key" = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw':: VARCHAR AND
    "public"."visit"."when_" >= CAST ('2016-11-03' AS TIMESTAMP ):: TIMESTAMP )
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', "public"."visit"."when_":: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles')
ORDER BY date_trunc('day', "public"."visit"."when_":: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles') ASC;

GroupAggregate  (cost=14018.92..14022.71 rows=138 width=45) (actual time=102.605..102.634 rows=6 loops=1)
  Output: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone))), count(visit.visitor), count(DISTINCT visit.visitor)
  Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone)))
  ->  Sort  (cost=14018.92..14019.26 rows=138 width=45) (actual time=102.568..102.580 rows=38 loops=1)
        Output: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone))), visit.visitor
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone)))
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=12529.29..14014.02 rows=138 width=45) (actual time=101.423..102.538 rows=38 loops=1)
              Output: date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone)), visit.visitor
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.visit  (cost=12528.73..13080.60 rows=138 width=117) (actual time=101.263..101.451 rows=38 loops=1)
                    Output: visit.when_, visit.visitor, visit.launch_key
                    Recheck Cond: (((visit.store_key)::text = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw'::text) AND (visit.when_ >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                    Heap Blocks: exact=38
                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=12528.73..12528.73 rows=138 width=0) (actual time=101.239..101.239 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on visit_store_key_idx  (cost=0.00..1762.64 rows=23727 width=0) (actual time=1.034..1.034 rows=4863 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((visit.store_key)::text = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw'::text)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on visit_when__idx  (cost=0.00..10765.77 rows=326561 width=0) (actual time=99.087..99.087 rows=843286 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (visit.when_ >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
              ->  Index Only Scan using launch_pkey on public.launch  (cost=0.56..6.75 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=38)
                    Output: launch.launch_key
                    Index Cond: (launch.launch_key = (visit.launch_key)::text)
                    Heap Fetches: 38
Planning time: 1.225 ms
Execution time: 102.714 ms
```

The new query joins on the new jsonb `stops` column (populated from the old visit.launch_key column).

Data was migrated such that if `visit.launch_key` contained `'abc'`, `visit.stops` now contains `['abc']`.

I'd expect the GIN index we put on `stops` to enable this query to perform comparably to the old query, but the performance is really bad:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE)
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', "public"."visit"."when_" :: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'),
    count("public"."visit"."visitor"),
    count(DISTINCT "public"."visit"."visitor")
FROM "public"."visit" join "public"."launch" ON ("public"."visit"."stops" ? "public"."launch"."launch_key")
        WHERE (
        "public"."visit"."store_key" = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw':: VARCHAR AND
        "public"."visit"."when_" >= CAST ('2016-11-03' AS TIMESTAMP ):: TIMESTAMP )
        GROUP BY date_trunc('day', "public"."visit"."when_":: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles')
        ORDER BY date_trunc('day', "public"."visit"."when_":: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles') ASC;

GroupAggregate  (cost=7643302.27..7648253.15 rows=128 width=45) (actual time=54946.583..54946.605 rows=5 loops=1)
  Output: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone))), count(visit.visitor), count(DISTINCT visit.visitor)
  Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone)))
  ->  Sort  (cost=7643302.27..7644539.43 rows=494864 width=45) (actual time=54946.535..54946.539 rows=34 loops=1)
        Output: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone))), visit.visitor
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone)))
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=11758.37..7596496.37 rows=494864 width=45) (actual time=54648.912..54946.507 rows=34 loops=1)
              Output: date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone)), visit.visitor
              Join Filter: (visit.stops ? (launch.launch_key)::text)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 134025620
              ->  Seq Scan on public.launch  (cost=0.00..157554.25 rows=3866125 width=72) (actual time=0.015..1381.991 rows=3941931 loops=1)
                    Output: launch.launch_key
              ->  Materialize  (cost=11758.37..12270.96 rows=128 width=126) (actual time=0.000..0.005 rows=34 loops=3941931)
                    Output: visit.when_, visit.visitor, visit.stops
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.visit  (cost=11758.37..12270.32 rows=128 width=126) (actual time=135.903..136.041 rows=34 loops=1)
                          Output: visit.when_, visit.visitor, visit.stops
                          Recheck Cond: (((visit.store_key)::text = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw'::text) AND (visit.when_ >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=34
                          ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=11758.37..11758.37 rows=128 width=0) (actual time=135.879..135.879 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on visit_store_key_idx  (cost=0.00..1762.64 rows=23727 width=0) (actual time=64.278..64.278 rows=4859 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((visit.store_key)::text = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw'::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on visit_when__idx  (cost=0.00..9995.41 rows=303313 width=0) (actual time=70.842..70.842 rows=716638 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (visit.when_ >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Planning time: 0.285 ms
Execution time: 54946.700 ms
```

I don't understand why our old query cuts the sort cost so much, while the new one does not. Is there anything that can be done to make the query that joins on `launch` using the jsonb `stops` column perform reasonably?

Postgres version:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.4
```

Comment: I've edited the fast query to include the compete execution plan, but the slow one is a challenge, as it's really slow (hours at least, maybe days, maybe heat death of the universe).

Comment: Can you please change the posted execution plan for the fast query to use the same store_key as you now use for the slow query?

Comment: Updated so the queries use the same store_key. It shows that the sort costs have an even wider margin now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not ideal, I was able to find a workaround mainly cribbing from this blog post:
https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/the-lazy-analysts-guide-to-postgres-json.html

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, VERBOSE)
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', "public"."visit"."when_" :: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'),
    count("public"."visit"."visitor"),
    count(DISTINCT "public"."visit"."visitor")
FROM visit join
            (
                    select visit_key, trim(jsonb_array_elements(stops)::text, '"') stop
                    from visit
                    where visit.store_key = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw' AND
                          visit.when_ >= '2016-11-03'
            ) launches using (visit_key) join launch on (launch.launch_key = launches.stop)
WHERE (
    visit."store_key" = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw':: VARCHAR AND
    visit."when_" >= CAST ('2016-11-03' AS TIMESTAMP ):: TIMESTAMP )
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', visit."when_":: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles')
ORDER BY date_trunc('day', visit."when_":: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles') ASC;

GroupAggregate  (cost=26664.63..26664.66 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=176.278..176.308 rows=6 loops=1)
  Output: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone))), count(visit.visitor), count(DISTINCT visit.visitor)
  Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone)))
  ->  Sort  (cost=26664.63..26664.64 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=176.253..176.264 rows=39 loops=1)
        Output: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone))), visit.visitor
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone)))
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=25835.78..26664.62 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=174.998..176.208 rows=39 loops=1)
              Output: date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Los_Angeles'::text, (visit.when_)::timestamp with time zone)), visit.visitor
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=25835.23..26658.28 rows=1 width=77) (actual time=174.919..175.108 rows=39 loops=1)
                    Output: visit.when_, visit.visitor, (btrim((jsonb_array_elements(visit_1.stops))::text, '"'::text))
                    Hash Cond: ((visit_1.visit_key)::text = (visit.visit_key)::text)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.visit visit_1  (cost=12636.82..13267.36 rows=14000 width=128) (actual time=85.309..85.455 rows=39 loops=1)
                          Output: visit_1.visit_key, btrim((jsonb_array_elements(visit_1.stops))::text, '"'::text)
                          Recheck Cond: (((visit_1.store_key)::text = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw'::text) AND (visit_1.when_ >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=39
                          ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=12636.82..12636.82 rows=140 width=0) (actual time=85.252..85.252 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on visit_store_key_idx  (cost=0.00..1762.64 rows=23727 width=0) (actual time=1.366..1.366 rows=4864 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((visit_1.store_key)::text = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw'::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on visit_when__idx  (cost=0.00..10873.86 rows=329772 width=0) (actual time=82.313..82.313 rows=867471 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (visit_1.when_ >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=13196.66..13196.66 rows=140 width=92) (actual time=89.580..89.580 rows=39 loops=1)
                          Output: visit.when_, visit.visitor, visit.visit_key
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.visit  (cost=12636.82..13196.66 rows=140 width=92) (actual time=89.350..89.534 rows=39 loops=1)
                                Output: visit.when_, visit.visitor, visit.visit_key
                                Recheck Cond: (((visit.store_key)::text = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw'::text) AND (visit.when_ >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                Heap Blocks: exact=39
                                ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=12636.82..12636.82 rows=140 width=0) (actual time=89.327..89.327 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on visit_store_key_idx  (cost=0.00..1762.64 rows=23727 width=0) (actual time=0.900..0.900 rows=4864 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: ((visit.store_key)::text = 'ahBzfmdlYXJsYXVuY2gtaHVicg8LEgVTdG9yZRi53Ku8Cgw'::text)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on visit_when__idx  (cost=0.00..10873.86 rows=329772 width=0) (actual time=86.485..86.485 rows=867471 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (visit.when_ >= '2016-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
              ->  Index Only Scan using launch_pkey on public.launch  (cost=0.56..6.32 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.025..0.026 rows=1 loops=39)
                    Output: launch.launch_key
                    Index Cond: (launch.launch_key = (btrim((jsonb_array_elements(visit_1.stops))::text, '"'::text)))
                    Heap Fetches: 39
Planning time: 1.012 ms
Execution time: 176.449 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

> Data was migrated such that if visit.launch_key contained 'abc', visit.stops now contains ['abc'].

This seems like a really bad idea.  Why do you want to do that?  Is it too late to change your mind?

PostgreSQL can get a pretty good estimate of how selective `visit.store_key = parameter` is.  It has much less accurate information on how selective `visit.stops ? parameter`.

When the ? is only used as a filter, this probably isn't going to be so bad.  But when it is used as a join operator, this leads the planner to make very poor choices.

This is an acknowledged shortcoming and there has been some discussion of trying to improve this situation for a future version of PostgreSQL, but so far I don't think it has moved beyond discussion so I wouldn't be terrible optimistic.  But even if it were fixed, I would still expect a scalar which is a scalar is going to work better than a scalar dressed up as an array.

By the way, you asked why it slows down your sort.  It doesn't.  The time reported for the sort operation includes the time needed to generate the data that is to be sorted.  The sort itself is very quick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jjanes. The reason we migrated the data this way was to allow this visit to be one-to-many on launch. Sure, there are other ways to do that but a jsonb array seemed like an especially good fit for us. Also, the slowness does still seem to come from the sort to me. The cost of one is 99958.13..99968.26 and the other is much higher at 7643302.27..7644539.43. I'm mostly just curious as to why that would be the case.

Comment: Re-reading your answer again... are you saying that the planner is able to use the GIN index for a filter using ?, but not in a join? I suppose that would explain it (and paints us into a corner!). Would you happen to have any links to the discussions on that?

Comment: The cost of the sort includes the cost of all nodes below that sort.  It is the nodes below the sort which the primary difference.

Comment: It can use a GIN index for ? in join, it is just choosing not to because it mistakingly thinks using it will be slower.  Bad selectivity estimates on filter operations can also lead to very bad plans, but bad estimates on join operations are even more likely to cause such problems.  That is just a general rule of thumb, not a hard and fast rule.